# как получить html страницу с https на t-sql

Tags: sql-server

как получить html страницу с https на t-sql[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: не могу получить html страницу с сайта https, с другими сайтами все работало, прикрепил скрин

Comment: смотрите свою ХП Inet_ReadUrl